# Does the separate call goes to server to render the image in img tag on jsp file?

Tags: java, image

I know the how to show th image on jsp file. But never thought how it works? I mean Does image get rendered with html page right at the time when jsp page 
    is evaluated to html content by webserver   and transferred to browser as bytes along with other html or it does not happen this way.
    I did discuss with my collegues but they were not sure too. One of them told me that when you request any JSP page from server, jsp page is evaluated
    to corresponding html content and images are not rendered at this point of time.So when browser gets this html page and see the tag like below,browser
    makes separate call to server to for each image.Is that correct?If yes ,if there are 50 images on jsp page, will 50 request go to server to download the
    image. He also mentioned not only images but javascript also included in JSP this way only?
    I am not sure when and how the image included in jsp page is requested? Could not get this fact cleared
    thru googling too. T

```
src="getImage.jsp"
```

The question came in my mind because on change of some value in dropdown, i want to to change the image . I thought i could do it
    on client side. But if go by the approach mentioned in the last, looks like image has to be downloaded from server first.

Comment: Just like any html page, a separate request is made for each image after the html page has been received.

Comment: @M Sach : yes, that's the same process. JSP is just a way to build the HTML (or sometimes other kind of files).

Comment: With this i can say  the more images/or any other resource like javascript,css i include in jsp page, the more will be response time as separate call goes for each resource.Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very hard to tell what you're asking. If you mean, does an image you include in your JSP page via an `img` tag (e.g., `<img src="/path/to/image.jpg">`) somehow get "baked into" your JSP page when it's compiled into a servlet by your JSP container, the answer is no. The browser will request the JSP page, get back HTML et. al., and then request the image.

Comment: Thanks T.j Crowder.Is is the same procedure for sending the javascript file to browser with tag
<script language="JavaScript" src="script/OpenPopupWin.js?ver=4.3.13"></script>? I mean 
 browser will request the JSP page, get back HTML et. al., and then request the javascript file.RIGHT?

Comment: @MSach: Right. It's the same with all resources you link to -- images, scripts, CSS files. There are tools that can put your JavaScript and CSS inline automatically (Google's `mod_pagespeed` for Apache, for instance), but the JSP layer doesn't come into it. You won't usually find tools that will embed *images* in the HTML markup because that requires `data:` URIs, which are relatively recent and either unsupported or spottily-supported by older browsers. And of course, the more you combine everything into the page, the less re-use you get out of the browser cache.

Comment: One last point.With this i can say  the more images/or any other resource like javascript,css i include in jsp page, the more will be response time as separate call goes for each resource.Is that correct?

Comment: @MSach: Yes indeed. That's why the usual recommendation (for instance, [in this famous list from YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)) is to keep the number of separate resources required to a minimum. That's why you see tools to combine JavaScript files, combine CSS files, make sprite images, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change images based on a dropdown I'd suggest using javascript.

First load all the images in javascript objects (on loading of the page)
then in the onchange event of the dropdown change the image.

googling for "preloading images javascript" should provide ample examples

returning an image from a jsp file is also possible

Write code in your jsp that writes the byte stream of an image to the jsp writer, make sure you set the mime type correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Images are downloaded exactly as all other resources do, and get rendered by your browser.

If you ask if 50 instances of *the same image in a single page* will be downloaded 50 times, the answer depends on the HTTP caching policy headers for the particular image resource - if they allow a resource to be cached, it will get cached by your browser and will be downloaded over the wire only once.

Comment: If there are 50 `img` tags in a document with the same `src`, I ***very much doubt*** any major browser would download that image more than once, regardless of caching headers, in order to initially render that page. If the caching headers don't allow caching and you add or set the image later via script (or of course, load another page using the same image), *then* the browser should re-acquire it, but not for each `img` tag in the initial page load.

Comment: I'm missing the details now, but if the resource caching is explicitly forbidden ("Cache-control: no-cache") AND the cached resource has been evicted from the **memory cache** (AND it **should not** be stored into the disk cache) due to some circumstances (e.g. the cache is full), it will be re-retrieved even while loading sub-resources for the same page.

Comment: Perhaps in some very edgy edge cases. :-) I'd expect it in the main for that not to be the case.

Comment: Yes, naturally, that would never be the general case in any browser :)